# Inability to get into the database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, model

This is how when I try to throw something in the database, then it will not get into the database.

I've tried to debug it and there will nothing at all.

**create.cshtml**

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="form-group">
     <div class="col-md-12">
       <label>E-Mail</label>
       @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input-lg", placeholder = "Skriv email", } })
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**UsersAccount.cs (Model)**

```
namespace MentorOrdblind_MVC.Models.Konto
{
    public class UsersAccount
    {
        [Key]
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "EmailAddress")]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        [Required(ErrorMessage="Husk at skriv en email!")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**KontoController.cs (Controller)**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult CreateUsers(UsersAccount UsersAccount)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var CreateAnAccount = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(b => b.Email == UsersAccount.Email);
        if (CreateAnAccount == null)
        {
            CreateAnAccount.Email = UsersAccount.Email;//email
            db.Users.InsertOnSubmit(CreateAnAccount);
            db.SubmitChanges(); // save
            RedirectToAction("login", "KontoController");
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.MessageError = "Denne brugere findes i vores system.";
        }
    }
   return View();
```

}

There is no error until all when it, but there comes just not disclosed in the database and writes no error message if I eg leave it blank !.

How can it be that I just no getting into the database. and yes table written really etc. but throw it into the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var CreateAnAccount = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(b => b.Email == UsersAccount.Email);
```

means your finding the first `User` with that email. You next line of code is

```
if (CreateAnAccount == null)
```

which means if a user was found then the code inside this code block will never be called, so you never save anything to the database. On the other hand, if no user was found, then the first line of code inside the `if` block

```
CreateAnAccount.Email = UsersAccount.Email;
```

would throw a `NullReferenceException` because `CreateAnAccount` is `null` and you cannot access a property of `null`.

Change your code to

```
var CreateAnAccount = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(b => b.Email == UsersAccount.Email);
if (CreateAnAccount != null)
{
    ....
```

Comment: Thanks for helpen!!, Can u plases giv me +1

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (CreateAnAccount == null)
{
    CreateAnAccount = new UsersAccount();
    ....
```

or more better

```
if (CreateAnAccount == null)
{
    // should just content into the database.
    db.Users.InsertOnSubmit(UsersAccount);

    // must save the contents.
    db.SubmitChanges(); // save

   ...
```

**EDIT**

```
if (CreateAnAccount == null)
{
    // I suspect that your User class has Email property
    CreateAnAccount = new User(); 

    CreateAnAccount.Email = UsersAccount.Email;//email

    ...
```

Comment: If I make the last that you have written you will see it with errors, and the first I can in no way make all ..

Comment: I don't understand what you say. Can you more specific. Which error, where?

Comment: sorry - I mean if I make the first code you've written so give it to me this one error. -> **Cannot implicitly convert type 'FirstMVC.Models.Konto.UsersAccount' to 'FirstMVC.Models.Linq.User'**

If I make the other that you have written all the past then comes this error. -> **Argument 1: cannot convert from 'FirstMVC.Models.Konto.UsersAccount' to 'FirstMVC.Models.Linq.User' ** and its here: **The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.Linq.Table<FirstMVC.Models.Linq.User>.InsertOnSubmit(FirstMVC.Models.Linq.User)' has some invalid arguments**

Comment: The throw still not entered into the database. :(